# Evaluate model attribute in slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I wanted to evaluate **name.place_location** which I am passing to slim partial through locals,

```
- name."#{place}_location".each do |place|
  ....
```

This cannot be evaluated since place_location is a string, as it is model attribute.

How can I do this in slim

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the [Object#send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-send)?

```
- name.send("#{place}_location").each do |place|
  ...
```